# send gcm message in groups of 1000 users to all 10000 users

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

i am using following code to send gcm message using php and mysqldb i have successfully send the gcm message and received it on the device however the android guidelines state that gcm message should be send in batch of 1000 each http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#multicast

now my question is how can we send gcm messages in lots of 1000 to a database of say 10,000 registered users.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'keys_value');

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    echo json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false)
        die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;

}

$pushStatus = '';

if(!empty($_GET['push'])) {

    $query = "SELECT gcm_regId FROM gcm_users";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

        $gcmRegIds = array();
        while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

            array_push($gcmRegIds, $query_row['gcm_regId']);

        }

    }
    $pushMessage = $_POST['message'];
    if(isset($gcmRegIds) && isset($pushMessage)) {

        $message = array('price' => $pushMessage);
        $pushStatus = sendPushNotification($gcmRegIds, $message);

    }   
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</h1>
    <form method = 'POST' action = 'send_all.php/?push=1'>
        <div>
            <textarea rows = 2 name = "message" cols = 23 placeholder = 'Messages to Transmit via GCM'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type = 'submit' value = 'Send Push Notification via GCM'>
        </div>
        <p><h3><?php echo $pushStatus ?></h3></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check here for full code : [Send Firebase Notification to more than 1000 users at a time from PHP](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/0105fd8cb7678f3e4b7fef2cb313db0a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make $gcmRegIds to be a 2D array and then foreach it to push msg:

```
if(!empty($_GET['push'])) {

    $query = "SELECT gcm_regId FROM gcm_users";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

        $gcmRegIds = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $i++;
            $gcmRegIds[floor($i/1000)][] = $query_row['gcm_regId'];
        }

    }
    $pushMessage = $_POST['message'];
    if(isset($gcmRegIds) && isset($pushMessage)) {

        $message = array('price' => $pushMessage);
        $pushStatus = array();
        foreach($gcmRegIds as $val) $pushStatus[] = sendPushNotification($val, $message);

    }   
}
```

Comment: i am quiet new to php could you give the complete code please explain how it would work

Comment: this only sends message to 1000 users after that it stops what can be done to send message to all 10000 users

Comment: How do you then execute the ` $pushStatus[] = sendPushNotification($val, $message);` to send out the messages?

Comment: Check here for full code : [Send Firebase Notification to more than 1000 users at a time from PHP](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/0105fd8cb7678f3e4b7fef2cb313db0a)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i did for my scenario to resolve for FCM .You can also ignore some parts of the  code

```
<?php

$saved_tokens=array(); // could be more than 1000 token the maximum size as per google FCM requirement
//$count=1;
$ID_SETS = array_chunk($saved_tokens, 1000); // make a  group of 1000 items in each set
foreach ($ID_SETS as $value_ids) {
    // echo "Chunk  ".$count."<br>";
    sendFCM_Notification("what_ever_parameter_data",$value_ids);

    foreach ($value_ids as $value_i ) { // you can remove this part its not neccessary
        //echo " ---- contents of Chunk ".$count ."with Value".$value_i."<br>";

    }
    // $count++;    

}
function sendFCM_Notification($what_ever_parameter,$reg_ids_array){

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $reg_ids_array,
             'data' => $what_ever_parameter
            );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key = YOUR_KEY ',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;

}



?>
```