# Gcm message not sent to more that 1000 users

Tags: php, android, arrays, google-cloud-messaging

Gcm message not sent to more that 1000 users , gcm has its own limit of sending message to 1000 users so the idea is to divide the users in batch of 1000 each i tried that but the gcm message is received by first 1000 users only how can we send the message in batches of 1000 each, in a total of say 5000 users, so that all users get the message i am new to php please explain the working

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    //echo json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false)
        die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;

}

$pushStatus = '';
function getGCMCount(){
 $total = "";
 $query = "SELECT count(gcm_regId) as total FROM gcm_users";
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
          $total = $query_row['total'] / 1000;     
    }  

    return $total;
}

if(!empty($_GET['push'])) {

    $query = "SELECT gcm_regId FROM gcm_users";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

        $gcmRegIds = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $i++;
            $gcmRegIds[floor($i/1000)][] = $query_row['gcm_regId'];
//echo $i . "</br>" ; 
            }
        }      


    $pushMessage = $_POST['message'];
    if(isset($gcmRegIds) && isset($pushMessage)) {


        $pushStatus = array();
//echo "</br> counnt of messages send is". count($pushStatus);

        foreach($gcmRegIds as $key=>$val)

{

$message = array('price' =>  $pushMessage);
//$message1 = array($key=>$val);
//$c = (array_merge($message ,$message1 ));
$pushStatus[] = sendPushNotification($val, $message);
//echo $key;

}
    }   
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</h1>
    <form method = 'POST' action = 'send_all.php/?push=1'>
        <div>
            <textarea rows = 2 name = "message" cols = 23 placeholder = 'Messages to Transmit via GCM'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type = 'submit' value = 'Send Push Notification via GCM'>
        </div>
        <p><h3><?php //echo $pushStatus  . "<br>"?></h3></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried sending the message 5 times, 1,000 at a time? Maybe you can add some delay between each batch, so don't send immediately after the first batch of messages are sent, but wait for it to process. Just giving you some suggestions. :)

Comment: i have tried sending it 1000 times hence i came up with the above issue

Comment: See the following post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128526/send-gcm-message-in-groups-of-1000-users-to-all-10000-users

Answer (score 0):

Refer this snippet for sending messages to more than 1000 users

```
<?php 

    //Sample for sending notification to more than 1000 users
    $mPushNotification = $push->getMessage();


    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT gcm_regid FROM gcm_users");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $tokens = array();
    while ($token = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         array_push($tokens, $token['gcm_regid']);
    }


    $firebase = new Firebase();

    $total = count($tokens);

    $groups = ceil($total/800);
        $currentval=ceil($total/$groups);
        $firebase = new Firebase(); 
        for ($i=0; $i <$groups; $i++) { 

            $val=($i*$currentval)+1;
            $total = ($i+1)*$currentval;
            $resToken = getSpecificToken($val,$total);
            $result1 = $firebase->send($resToken, $mPushNotification);

        }

    function getSpecificToken($upper,$lower)
    {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM gcm_users LIMIT $upper,$lower");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $tokens = array();
            while ($token = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                array_push($tokens, $token['gcm_regid']);
            }
        return $tokens;
    }

 function getMessage() {
        $res = array();
        $res['data']['id'] = 1;
        $res['data']['title'] = "TestTitle";
        $res['data']['message'] = "TestMessage : Hello";
        return $res;
    }
?>

//Firebase File
<?php 

class Firebase {

    public function send($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    /*
    * This function will make the actual curl request to firebase server
    * and then the message is sent 
    */
    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

        //importing the constant files
        require_once 'Config.php';

        //firebase server url to send the curl request
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        //building headers for the request
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        //Initializing curl to open a connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //Setting the curl url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        //setting the method as post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        //adding headers 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //disabling ssl support
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        //adding the fields in json format 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        //finally executing the curl request 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        //Now close the connection
        curl_close($ch);

        //and return the result 
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```